# What is the usual approach to escape an element which is non existing (like jQuery does)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I'm having

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('top_button')[0];
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { /* some here */ }));
```

and the class *undefined* I'm getting a `TypeError`. I'm wondering what is the usual approach to escape this. Would it be

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('top_button')[0] || {};
```

or should I do this different? How is jQuery doing this, because when I'm using `$('.top_button')` and the element is not there, it just returns an object.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: jQuery has its own (more complex) way, returning an iterable jQuery object every time (which may contain 0 found elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want just the *first* one, then I agree with Praveen that an `if` is the clearest, simplest solution, though I usually do it in a different place:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('top_button')[0];
if (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { /* some here */ }));
}
```

The collection returned by `getElementsByClassName` reliably, cross-browser, gives you `undefined` if there's no element at the index you asked for (just like JavaScript arrays).

But I would use `querySelector` rather than `getElementsByClassName`, since you only want the first and there's no need to build a list, and `querySelector` is on all modern browsers, and also IE8 (whereas IE8 lacks `getElementsByClassName`).

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.top_button');
if (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { /* some here */ }));
}
```

`querySelector` accepts any CSS selector (including complex ones) and returns the first matching element, or `null`. Its cousin `querySelectorAll` returns a list (which can be empty if none match).

If you want to hook the event on **all** matching elements, [Quentin has you covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268372/157247).

---

> How is jQuery doing this, because when I'm using $('.top_button') and the element is not there, it just returns an object.

jQuery objects are wrappers around sets of DOM elements (usually, they *can* be wrappers around other things, but in typical use they're DOM elements). So when you do `$('.top_button')`, you get a jQuery object which is a wrapper around a set with nothing in it. You can make calls on that jQuery object, like `.on`, and they don't fail (because the jQuery object exists), but they don't *do* anything, either (because there are no elements in the set for it to do anything with).

I'm not suggesting it, but you could do the same thing yourself with `querySelectorAll`. (jQuery predates `querySelectorAll` by some years, originally John Resig built an entire selector engine for it. Modern browsers make that unnecessary in a jQuery-like thing, unless you want to add your own CSS selector stuff like jQuery's `:has`.)

Just by way of illustrating what jQuery is doing (purely conceptually):

```
function DomQuery(selector) {
    // Get the matching elements, as an array (the `slice` thing turns
    // the collection returned by `querySelectorAll` into an array)
    this.elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(selector));
}
DomQuery.prototype.on = function(eventName, handler) {
    this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    });
    return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
new DomQuery(".top_button").on("click", function() {
    // do something
});
```

We can make that more jQuery-like by making `new` optional:

```
function domQuery(selector) {
    // If not called via `new`, do that
    if (!(this instanceof domQuery)) {
        return new domQuery(selector);
    }

    // Get the matching elements, as an array (the `slice` thing turns
    // the collection returned by `querySelectorAll` into an array)
    this.elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(selector));
}
domQuery.prototype.on = function(eventName, handler) {
    this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    });
    return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
domQuery(".top_button").on("click", function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Man! I didn't see this answer. Wow! Ah!!! `Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 3 hours.` `:(`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple `if`:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('top_button');
if (btn.length > 0) {
  btn = btn[0];
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { /* some here */ }));
}
```

Or you can also check for `typeof` to be `"undefined"`.

Comment: Why are you always soo fast?? I am typing the same stuff and then I see your answer appearing again haha

Comment: Don't ask me. There's another guy named TJ. He's faster than lightspeed. And there's Quentin.

Comment: Ha :-) I took typing in high school. Nearly the best advice my mother ever gave me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just typing doesn't work out. Coz I didn't learn typing, the passion towards the technology and the helping tendency does.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @PraveenKumar, you can check for the length but you can also check if a variable is undefined by

```
if (typeof btn === "undefined") {
    //do stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery stores all the results in an array. When you call `on`, it loops over that array and applies the event handler to each item in it. If there are zero items, a standard for loop will stop immediately.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('top_button');
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() { /* some here */ }));
}
```